# Script to change h3 class into h2 class

Tags: php

There is some code in a php file of the theme that needs to become h2 instead of h3. I can't do this with a child theme, because it is in an include file.

This is a snippet of the piece of code I like to change:

```
$ret .= '<div class="gdlr-item-title-wrapper gdlr-item ' . $item_class . ' ">';

                $ret .= '<div class="gdlr-item-title-head">';
                if(!empty($atts['title'])){
                    $ret .= '<h3 class="gdlr-item-title gdlr-skin-title gdlr-skin-border">' . $atts['title'] . '</h3>';
                }
                if( !empty($atts['carousel']) ){
                    $ret .= '<div class="gdlr-item-title-carousel" >';
                    $ret .= '<i class="icon-angle-left gdlr-flex-prev"></i>';
                    $ret .= '<i class="icon-angle-right gdlr-flex-next"></i>';
                    $ret .= '</div>';
                }
```

I have been looking for a way to do this. I read about some things, and thought maybe this could work. But i am affraid it did not work for me yet. Am I doing it all wrong?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(function () {
            $("gdlr-item-title gdlr-skin-title gdlr-skin-border").click(function () {
                $("h3").replaceWith(function () {
                    return "<h2>" + $(this).text() + "</h2>";
                });
            });
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you need to put . before referring to class in jQuery like`.gdlr-item-title`

Comment: Thank you for your answer Divyank, but that does not seem to do anything too. I got an error on the $ is not a function.. I changed it to this:   jQuery(function($) {                                        instead of   $(function () {            The error is gone, but is does not change the h3 in a h2 unfortunately.

Comment: try to add log in console with`console.log('test or whatever')` in click function, check if its working

Comment: I am sorry Divyank, I don't understand what you mean. What should I try exactly?

Comment: change your code with this and check if you are getting any output in your browsers console `<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(function () {
            $(".gdlr-skin-border").click(function () {
   
    console.log(this)
                $("h3").replaceWith(function () {
                    return "<h2>" + $(this).text() + "</h2>";
                });
            });
        });
});
</script>`

Comment: Hey Divyank, thank you. I got an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: can you attach SS ?

Comment: Hi Divyank, sorry to have to ask, but what do yo mean by SS?

Answer (score 0):

replace your JQuery with this

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').on('click', '.gdlr-skin-border', function() {

            $("h3").replaceWith(function () {
                return "<h2>" + $(this).text() + "</h2>";
            });
        })   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Divyank, thank you again. I tried it, but now i get this error "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"

Comment: So I tried to change the first line with this... jQuery(document).ready(function($) {           The error goes away, but the h3 is not changed to a h2. I don't get it.